# Elasticsearch asciifolding not working properly

Tags: elasticsearch

I've created this test index using marvel plugin:

```
POST /test
{
   "index" : {
      "analysis" : {
         "analyzer" : {
            "folding": {
              "tokenizer": "standard",
              "filter":  [ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And I'm making the analyze request like this:

```
GET /test/_analyze?analyzer=folding&text=olá
```

And I'm getting the result:

```
{
    "tokens": [
          {
             "token": "ol",
             "start_offset": 0,
             "end_offset": 2,
             "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
             "position": 1
          }
       ]
}
```

But I need to have an "ola" token instead of the "ol" only. According to the documentation it's properly configured:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/asciifolding-token-filter.html

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is weird, if I do the same thing I do get back the token "ola". I just copied your commands.

Comment: As you tould bellow @user790999 there a bug at Sense Tool. Shoul report Sense developer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this, to prove that Elasticsearch does a good job in the end. I suspect the Sense interface is not passing the correct text to the analyzer.

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "folding": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter":  [ "lowercase", "asciifolding" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "folding"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /my_index/test/1
{
  "text": "olá"
}

GET /my_index/test/_search
{
  "fielddata_fields": ["text"]
}
```

The result:

```
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "my_indexxx",
            "_type": "test",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "text": "olá"
            },
            "fields": {
               "text": [
                  "ola"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
```

Comment: That's right! It's a problema with the browser encoding and sense interface!

Comment: It works using the browser directly:

http://localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze?analyzer=folding&text=ol%C3%A1

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the more [recent versions of elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-asciifolding-tokenfilter.html), you can pass `"asciifolding"` token filter like this:

```
PUT index_name
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": { 
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample query:

```
POST index_name/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",
  "text": "olá"
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "ola",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 3,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The examples above did not work for me .. with some adjustments, the following worked in Elastic search 7.3.1:

Delete the index (if previously created):

```
DELETE /my_index
```

Define the mappings for the index:

```
PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "folding": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "folding",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Add some data:

```
POST my_index/_doc/1
{"text":"olá"}
```

Perform a search:

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "ola"
    }
  }
}
```